# Database table entry stooped when ajax code is on in cusom plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

when ajax code is in running mode,at that time database entry stopped,when i comment ajax code that time database operation performed successfully, right now i am using ajax code and database insert code in same file.i know that it is better to use ajax code in another file,but i don't know how to separate ajax code in separate file and how to call that file in plugin main file.

```
<?php 
 function add_new_Student() {

    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {

        global $wpdb;
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $contact = $_POST['contact'];
//        var_dump($_POST);

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'Student_list';
        $wpdb->insert(
                "$table_name", //table
                array('name' => $name, 'role' => $role, 'contact' => $contact), //data
                array('%s', '%s', '%s') //data format
        );

        $message.="Student Added";
    }
    ?>
    <div class="container">    

        <form method="post" id="frmdemo" class="form-horizontal myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Name">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name1" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Role">Role:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role1" name="role" placeholder="Role">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Contact">Contact:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="contact1" name="contact" placeholder="Contact">
                </div>
            </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="insert"/>Submit</button>  
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="reset"/>Reset</button>

                    <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>
                    <div id="success_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>              

        </form>
    </div>

// ajax code here
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>         
<script>
$("#frmdemo").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name1").val();
    var role = $("#role1").val();
    var contact = $("#contact1").val();


    if(name == "" || role == "" || contact == "") {
        $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
    } else {
        $("#error_message").html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'post-form.php',
            data: "name="+name+"&role="+role+"&contact="+contact,
            success: function(data){
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                    $('').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 2000 );

            }
        });
    }
})
</script>   


    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ajax `url: 'post-form.php',` try to add `url:'<?php echo get_permalink();?>',`
or

```
url: '<?php echo plugins_url("your_plugin_name/folderName/post-form.php"); ?>',
```

Comment: Used this code but still ajax works fine,but databse entry can't performed. 
  url: '<?php echo plugins_url("plugin_name/post-form.php"); ?>',

Comment: remove the function simple start from isset($_POST['insert']) coz you are not calling the function

Comment: actually this is plugins's file,the function is used at plugin's main file,so plugin is necessary to use,my question is i want to perform both action(ajax,database operation) at a same time

Comment: yes, ajax is working fine, when i comment ajax code then database operation works fine,but i want both operation at a same time.

Comment: check what data is sent by ajax

Comment: Thanks in advance,when complete, tell me

Comment: tell me about your plugin

Comment: When you activate this plugin,it will create option in word press admin page,and you can add student data by using add Add new button,automatic database tale creation and deletion functionality is also included with this plugin.It is demo plugin for testing purpose.

Comment: how much you will pay

Comment: where and please try to customize it

Comment: Both action can't perform at same time

Comment: Upload zip file folder and valid for 1 hour,send me download link,thanks in advance link:https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: Thank you so much code is working absolutely fine,i will try to discuss my problem in word press with you at stack overflow...